# Visual Studio Team Services: How to ensure build server (AzureVM) is running before queuing a build

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, automated-builds

We have an AzureVM being used for a VSTS build server.  In order to save costs, we also have that build server turn off at 6pm EST every day.

We'd like VSTS to automatically be able to restart the VM (if not already running) upon queuing a build, but there doesnt seem to be any support for this scenario.

Thought about doing a powershell task, but thats after the build starts, so you still get the "cant schedule a build" error because the VM that all the build tasks will run from is still off.

How has anybody else solved this problem?

Comment: In your scenario,  one solution is that you could use VSTS agent to start your VM or use Azure runbook to start your VM with Azure Power Shell.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT so how to do that?